# How to access a method of app component in other component or service in React JS

Tags: reactjs

I am working on a react application and want to implement react-notifications-component for notifications. I don't know how to call it's addNotification method from every component.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to call a function of a component in another component, you have to pass a reference to it through `props`.